# Detecting if HDD is connected thru USB or by other means without WMI

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I would like to find out if connected drive is USB connected, thru SATA, IDE, eSATA or Firewire. Is there a way to find it without using WMI? I'm using this code to get some information.

```
 DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
 foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives) {
    // DriveType.Fixed && DriveType.Removable

 }
```

Unfortunately this returns for all HDD's connected thru USB `DriveType.Fixed`, and only USB Sticks get to be `DriveType.Removable`.

I guess I am looking for something like this... just that I don't know what I am actually looking for. Unfortunately `GetVolumeInformation` doesn't provide the way to know the `InterfaceType`

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern long GetVolumeInformation(
        string PathName, 
        StringBuilder VolumeNameBuffer, 
        UInt32 VolumeNameSize, 
        ref UInt32 VolumeSerialNumber, 
        ref UInt32 MaximumComponentLength, 
        ref UInt32 FileSystemFlags, 
        StringBuilder FileSystemNameBuffer, 
        UInt32 FileSystemNameSize);
```

I would like to skip WMI. I do know I could find it with more or less this code:

```
  ManagementObjectSearch theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
  "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
```

but I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: What is it about WMI that makes you want to avoid it?

Comment: There's no `big` reason behind it. I would like to be able to skip it if possible. Always something new to learn for me. If there will be no `way` I'll use WMI then.

Comment: There is [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6559/How-To-get-the-usbdisk-s-drive-letter-properly) in C++ on CodeProject. Not very easy to translate in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the variation so specifically; but you'll have to use WMI.  Unfortunately, though a USB based hard-drive is removable it still utilizes an actual disk not flash memory. So the `DriveInfo` will more then likely consider it fixed.

The only alternative would be to import the `System.Management` Assembly.

You could retrieve the Bus Info of each drive.  Or possibly use this tool to retrieve [`HID Descriptions`](http://www.usb.org/). Or another tool which is normally used to write [custom drivers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/).

But this may be your best suite; as it includes a way to simply determine if the drive is considered *external* or *not*.  [Which obviously won't address the fixed / removable but will assist in targeting the type of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891854/how-to-determine-if-drive-is-external-drive).

Hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The Device Manager API is certainly capable of telling you which bus and controller each disk is attached to.  But it's not very p/invoke friendly.  I suggest writing this portion of the code in C++ and then making a C#-friendly interface either with C++/CLI or designed-for-p/invoke exports.

The core of this solution will be calling `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` to fetch the value associated with `SPDRP_BUSTYPEGUID`.  But getting the right `HDEVINFO` and `PSP_DEVINFO_DATA` handles will require some work.