# How to detect whether removable drive is pen-drive or external hard disk

Tags: c#

I  want to detect whether removable drive is pen-drive or external hard disk.

I have below code:

```
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
              //Here I want to detect whether removable drive is 
              //Pendrive or External Hard Disk
            }
        }
```

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly do you want to know? the amount of storage? or the storage type (flash vs spinning, magnetic discs)? physical size? ... and why?

Comment: I want to know unique serial number of removable drive.

After searching,I came to know there is not a common way to detect serial number of pen-drive and external HDD

Hence I am searching this      
 DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
     {
            if(Removable drive is pendrive) 
  {
   code to find Pendrive's unique serial number
  }

         if(Removable drive is external HDD) 
  { 
   code to find external HDD unique serial number
  }  
        }

Comment: please edit your question instead of writing new code in the comment (which, as you may see, is very hard to read). an other reason why, is that people should not have to read the comments to know the actual/current question.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test on my pc to see what types it returns for my drives and the `DriveType` for my USB drive is `DriveType.Removable` and for my external HDD (connected via usb cable) is `DriveType.Fixed` same as my C drive

according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

`DriveType.Removeable`:

> The drive is a removable storage device, such as a floppy disk drive or a USB flash drive.

`DriveType.Fixed`:

> The drive is a fixed disk.

so im assuming `DriveType.Fixed` also includes external HDDs

how to differentiate between an internal HDD and an external one, someone answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9891854/1498624)*, i haven't test it though

*also the OP on that question mentions that his external HDD is recognized as `DriveType.Fixed`

Comment: Thank you so much Gunther.That link helped me a lot.But problem that I am facing is of speed.It takes more than 25 seconds to detect external hard disks drive when i call that class in this loop foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()){}