# How to discover usb mass storage device (external hard drive) ?

Tags: c#, external, usb-drive, driveinfo

I have tried these 2 different function but it doesn't work as expected.
[How to determine if drive is external drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891854/how-to-determine-if-drive-is-external-drive) <- the method provided on this also returns true for usb thumbdrive. But, i am looking specifically for external hard drive.

```
       DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
       foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)     
       if (d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed && d.Name != "C:" + @"\"){}
```

Comment: In your estimation, what determines whether any particular USB flash-based mass storage is a "hard drive" or a "thumb drive"?  For the OS, the difference is partitioning.

Answer (score -2):

The DriveType enum also has a Removable property:

```
System.IO.DriveType driveType = drive.DriveType;
switch (driveType)
{
    case System.IO.DriveType.CDRom:
        break;
    case System.IO.DriveType.Fixed:
        // Local Drive
        break;
    case System.IO.DriveType.Network:
        // Mapped Drive
        break;
    case System.IO.DriveType.NoRootDirectory:
        break;
    case System.IO.DriveType.Ram:
        break;
    case System.IO.DriveType.Removable:
        // Usually a USB Drive
        break;
    case System.IO.DriveType.Unknown:
        break;
}
```

You can query for the type.