# Not able to detect Hard disk drive in C# application

Tags: c#, usb

I have written an api to get all external storage drives connected to my computer. But i am not able to detect hard disk drives.

```
private async Task GetAllDrivesConnected()
        {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
                    lock (this.myUsbDriveListLock)
                    {
                        foreach (var aDrive in drives .Where(theDrive => theDrive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && theDrive.IsReady))
                        {
                            DriveLetter_Array.Add(aDrive.Name);
                        }
                    }

                    string LatestPath = DriveLetter_Array.LastOrDefault();
                    this.SetCurrentUsbPath(LatestPath);
                    var DeviceMessageEventArgs = new DeviceMessageEventArgs { Drive = LatestPath, UsbAdded = true };
                    FireEventAddPathRemovePath(DeviceMessageEventArgs);
                });
            
        }
```

I am making use of WML queries to listen to device inserted event:

```
 private async Task DeviceNotification()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var InsertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
                myInsertionWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(InsertQuery);
                myInsertionWatcher.EventArrived += this.DeviceInsertedEvent;
                myInsertionWatcher.Start();

                var RemoveQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 3");
                myRemovalWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(RemoveQuery);
                myRemovalWatcher.EventArrived += this.DeviceRemovedEvent;
                myRemovalWatcher.Start();
            });
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `DriveType` an external hard drive would be if not `Removable` but have you checked if it shows as a different type?

Comment: It does not detect hard disk inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your comment if you actually checked for other `DriveType`s. If I run the following after having connected an external hard drive I get the output from the image:

```
DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.IsReady)
```

[image]

As you can see it has `DriveType` `Fixed`, even if it's connected through a USB port.

You may want to change your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var aDrive in drives .Where(theDrive => theDrive.IsReady))
{
    DriveLetter_Array.Add(aDrive.Name);
}
```

If you want to only see external hard drives, you may want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018438/3034273)

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding the wait for next event method after start

```
myInsertionWatcher.WaitForNextEvent();
```

Comment: Remember to keep each event in its own while loop, so you can wait for the next event. EX:  

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        myInsertionWatcher.WaitForNextEvent();
        await Task.Delay(0);
    }
});